# Directus M2M Field Display as Select Box in Admin Panel

Tags: directus

I'm trying to convert a data model that uses composite keys, but I know as of version 9.14 Directus doesn't support them. I use these keys to offer clients different items from the same table. To get around this limitation, I'm using M2M relationships that offers each client the same options:

[image]

1. The junction table just stores the keys to save the relationships. Is there a way to add another column from the related collection in the admin panel to define what the key represents? This would help clients understand what values are assigned.
2. Also these M2M relationships are options to be selected in new collections. Is it possible to use a M2M relationship in a Select Box to force only one option to be selected?
3. Lastly, is it possible to filter all collection items based on a client ID associated with a login ID? This would allow one data model to support multiple clients. Is it possible to use SQL queries to populate collections displayed in the admin panel?

Thanks in advance for any help and direction.

Thanks,

Brandon